# Convert.ChangeType to System.Type

Tags: c#

I have a System.Type stored in a variable.  I wish to Change an object's type to this type.

I have the following code, but cannot get the Type to change to the type.

Ideally I'd like: `var intTest3 =(MyType)Convert.ChangeType(test, MyType);`   to return an int, when : `MyType is a System.Int32`

Here's my working so far - where am I going wrong?

```
        // object to cast to int
        object test = 1;

        // INT32 type
        Type MyType = typeof(System.Int32);

        // explicit type int WORKS
        var intTest = (int)Convert.ChangeType(test, typeof(Int32));


        // explicit type to int WORKS
        var intTest2 = (int)Convert.ChangeType(test, MyType);

        // explicit type to int WORKS - but as object
        object intTest3 = Convert.ChangeType(test, MyType);


        // cast to my type DOESNT WORK
        var intTest3 =(MyType)Convert.ChangeType(test, MyType);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really about `Convert.ChangeType` - it's about casting. The type you're casting to has to be known at *compile time*, although it could be a generic type. In this case, as far as the compiler is concerned `MyType` could refer to *any* type. It doesn't "know" that it will definitely have the value `typeof(int)`, so it won't just emit a cast to `int`.

In this case, what would you expect the compile-time type of `intTest3` to be?

What's the bigger picture here? What are you *really* trying to do? How would you want to use the value of `intTest3`?

Comment: This isn't the best explanation of the problem, especially as the type is hard-coded.

Comment: I am translating data between 2 APIs.  One API provides an object containing data, and a variable containg the System.Type of this data.  These are set at compile time.

The other API requires that any input is if of the "correct type" - so I cannot send in just the object, but rather, if the object's type is "Int32", then it expects an Int32 variable.

So I guess the question is "How to cast an object to a type, that is known only at run time".

Comment: @bob: What would you expect such a cast to do? How would you expect to use the result? Pretend that "var" doesn't exist, as it's not *really* relevant here - how would you have declared `intTest3` otherwise? Can you use a generic method instead? (That would let you cast to `T` having passed in `typeof(T)` to `ConvertType` if necessary.) If you could post fuller code for how you want to use whatever you come up with, that would be helpful.

Comment: currently, I have a switch statement on MyType.
case Int32: Convert.ToInt32(test); break;
case Int64: Convert.ToInt64(test); break;

But was hoping to remove the ugly switch...

Comment: @bob: But what are you doing with the result of Convert.ToInt64 afterwards? The context is very important here.

Comment: It's being passed into an Api method.  The Api method is overloaded, so it can accept an input variable of any type, except for type Object.

Comment: @bob: Are, so you want to change which overload you call based on the value of a variable? Unless you're using C# 4 (in which case you could use `dynamic`) you're basically out of luck for clean solutions. Either stick with the switch or you'll need to find the right method with reflection.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supposed to.  MyType isn't a "type" as far as C# is concerned, it's a variable of type "Type".  The "type" of "MyType" is "Type", but you can't cast 1 to "Type".

In this situation, you've entered "reflection-land" but you're really trying to find a way out.  I'm sorry, but there's no way to get back to strongly-typed-land from this sort of situation.

One workaround you could try to do however, is to move that last line into another generic method, and then invoke the method generically:

```
public static void LeaveReflectionLand<T>(object value)
{
     T newItem = (T)value;
}
```

Then from outside, you'd have to do something like this:

```
this.GetType().GetMethod("LeaveReflectionLand", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(MyType).Invoke(null, test);
```

But of course, that's a huge and scary workaround.   Check Jon Skeet's answer... I think it put things clearly.

The long and the short of it is, as MyType is an instance of the class Type, it could represent any type at all.  It's a variable just like int, as far as the compiler is concerned.  It's not a proper "type" in and of itself, it's a variable that "describes" a type. Because it's a variable that describes a type, there's no way, at compile time, for the compiler to know the actual type described by MyType, so this sort of thing isn't allowed.

It's not unlike doing something like this:

```
int test = 1;
int MyType = 2;
int anotherTest = (MyType)test;
```

Obviously, you can't do this.  MyType is a variable of type Int32.  The same is true when the type of MyType is Type, only in that situation MyType is a variable of type Type.

The key to understanding this is the difference between the "Type class" and the "compiler type".

I hope this helps. It's not the easiest thing to explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

MyType is a `Type`, which is a variable containing the definition information of a struct / class.  Casting by putting the `type` in brackets e.g. `(int)value;` requires the item in the brackets to be an actual class or struct, not a variable.